# Optmization between nodes having several routes with price and distance as constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I'm designing an Android application where I'm trying to find an optimal solution in a situation like this:

Suppose we have several different routes between a source and destination, and each route has a different price and distance. How can we find the optimal route which has both the best distance and price?

That is, if we have 5 routes R1, R2, R3, R4, R5 between S and D with

```
distances    R2 30 miles ,        
             R3 40 miles ,                   
             R1 50 miles ,                   
             R5 60 miles ,                   
             R4 70 miles ,                   
             R6 80 miles                  

Price for  R1  $5 , 
           R6  $8 , 
           R3  $9 ,
           R5  $11 ,
           R2  $13 ,
           R4  $15
```

What is the best route between S and D?

I have seen algorithms like Dijkstra's and some others like the travelling salesman problem, but I couldn't relate any of them to this.

Is there some some algorithm, formula or model for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2):

This is solvable by A*/Dijkstra's algorithm, which is designed to find the best (lowest total cost) route from A to B on a graph, given a list of nodes, edges and their costs.

A* uses a greedy approach to find only the best path, while Dijkstra's algorithm finds the best path from one point to everywhere else on the graph. They are fundamentally the same algorithm just applied a bit differently.

Since you are interested in both lowest price and lowest distance, your 'cost' should either be a mathematical formula over both aspects of it (for instance, convert distance to price using fuel prices then combine that with price), or you should run the algorithm twice for each parameter.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Yes, simply [weight](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3468) the distance and price into a normalized *cost*. Use that cost in the A* or Dijkstra algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: There may not be a single optimal solution.

Long answer: If there are two conflicting goals such as price and distance and the shorter routes are the more expensive ones, than in fact all routes are optimal. They are called [Pareto optimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency). If you cannot decide on an a priori feasible weighting between such conflicting objectives, you have to defer the choice of picking a solution. But you can use the principles of pareto dominance to always obtain the smallest set of pareto optimal solutions.

Pareto dominance separates the possible states between two points in the objective space into them being either dominated or non-dominated. When one solution dominates another it is better in at least one objective and equal in the others. When two solutions are non-dominated the first is better in at least one objective, but the second is better in another objective. Thus if you treat all objectives equally there is no a priori optimal candidate, both are optimal.

For example you often see Google maps presenting alternative routes when asking for directions. These are routes that have a shorter distance, but take longer to drive. Usually it selects the fastest route first, so their a priori choice is time only.

Comment: +1 BTW: for google maps alternative routes are not necessarily shorter and longer. It can even happen (try hamburg -> rome) that you get an alternative which is longer and slower. search for "alternative routes in road networks"

Comment: Yes, that's true, alternatives probably don't fully build on the pareto concept.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find "**best distance and best price combined**", but the best distance and the best price can have two different ways, For example (A, B, C, D), we want to find a best way from A to D

1. A --> B, distance 10, price 10
2. B --> D, distance 10, price 10
3. A --> C, distance 20, price 5
4. C --> D, distance 20, price 5

So you can get two diffenent ways by using two diff measures.

But by using some math, this problem can be simplified :

```
cost = distance * p1 + price * p2;
// p1 and p2 are some rate that can be learned,guessed .EG, p1 = 0.3, p2 = 0.7
```

So it is appropriate to use dij or some other graph algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: `distance * p1 + price * p2;` Actually only one term, p = `p1/p2` is needed, then multiply distance by that.

Comment: it is some like f(x) = g(x) + h(x) in A-star, it is necessary to give a function to measure the minimal "cost"

Comment: What I mean is, any cost function `distance * p1 + price * p2;` can be expressed as `distance * p + price;` where `p = p1/p2`, as all of the costs of the algorithm will be multiplied by the same constant factor (and thus the ordering will be maintained exactly). Just a minor nitpick.